# How to use the Kaggle way of displaying dataframes in Jupyter / Colaboratory

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, kaggle

Is it possible to use the kaggle way of displaying a dataset in Jupyter / Google Colaboratory?

I am looking for an interactive solution, ideally in the notebook cell. My current approach is to use df.plot(), df.head() df.tail() and seaborn to get sense of the data.

[image]

It seems like:
https://beakerx.com/

is able to add at least interactivity.

Other solutions:
dash (requires server)

Comment: Yes that is possible but involved.  Not sure if it's appropriate for SO.  Seems more like you need to hire a programmer.

Comment: Would be cool to have something like df.explore() that would yield an interactive dataframe in a notebook cell. Additonally df.explore(fullscreen=True) will open in separate tab.

Comment: Maybe plotly suits you: https://plot.ly/python/ipython-notebook-tutorial/